# How To Join Two Models with Different Column Names and Return All Instances?

Tags: python, django

> I aim to create a dataframe of the Top 3 Selling menu_items  in my Purchases table.  My thoughts are to create a join on the `Purchases` model with the `Menu_Item` model where `Purchases.menu_item = Menu_Item.title`.  I will convert the QuerySet to a DataFrame using `django_pandas.io`.  I plan to use the sum of `Menu_Item.price` associated with each distinct `Purchases.menu_item` to determine the Top 3 menu_items of all the records in the `Purchases` table.
> My problem is that I cannot join the two tables successfully.  I’ve scoured the interwebz for a working solution to join two models with different field names, which returns all instances, and I tried various solutions, but the scarce articles on this topic yielded no joy.

`models.py`

```
...
class MenuItem(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True,
                             verbose_name="Item Name")
    price = models.FloatField(default=0.00, verbose_name="Price")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500,
                                   verbose_name="Item Description")
    def __str__(self):
        return f"title={self.title}; price={self.price}"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/menu"

    def available(self):
        return all(X.enough() for X in self.reciperequirement_set.all())

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["title"]


class Purchase(models.Model):

    menu_item = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                  verbose_name="Menu Item")
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                     verbose_name="DateTime")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"menu_item=[{self.menu_item.__str__()}]; time={self.timestamp}"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/purchases"

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["menu_item"]
```

I tried adapting too many unsuccessful code fragments to reproduce here, so I am looking at starting with a clean slate.  I'm hoping you have an effective solution to share.  Your help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what you have tried, so it is hard for me (and other developers) to give precise suggestions.

Anyway, have you tried something like

```
purchases = Purchase.objects.values(
    'timestamp', 
    item_title=F('menu_item__title'), 
    item_price=F('menu_item__price'),
    item_desc=F('menu_item__description'))
```

This queryset will fetch all values in one sql connection.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I tried it and got just the last entered instance of a Purchase.
'''

>>> purchases = Purchase.objects.values(
...     'timestamp',
...     item_title=F('menu_item__title'),
...     item_price=F('menu_item__price'),
...     item_desc=F('menu_item__description'))
>>> df = read_frame(purchases)
>>> df
                         timestamp          item_title  item_price                                          item_desc
0 2022-10-09 22:52:56.159353+00:00  Django Djaffa Cake        8.25  Jaffa cakes are circular and have three layers...
>>>

```

Comment: Could you check if the `purchases` queryset itself returns only one object?

Comment: You are intuitive.  I checked and my queryset of `Purchase` yielded the same result: the last instance entered.

`
>>> from django_pandas.io import read_frame
>>> from django.db.models import F
>>> query = Purchase.objects.all()
>>> df = read_frame(query)
>>> df
   id                             menu_item                        timestamp
0   1  title=Django Djaffa Cake; price=8.25 2022-10-09 22:52:56.159353+00:00
`

Comment: I did a bit of further research and it turns out that the data returned is the last instance of the `Menu_Item` entered that was displayed.  That item had never been purchased.

Comment: Honestly this is out of my expectation. `purchases` queryset should return all `Purchase` objects, not just one. It is hard to determine at which point the queryset went wrong, but I would suggest you replicate the whole project, starting with a brand new virtual env, feeding data and mounting modules step by step.